# Search and filter products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've used two plugins in woocommerce one for product filter another for product search.
here the categories are ELITE, PREMIUM and tags are 625001, 625002, 625003.  Now the requirement is, if a customer searched a product like 'ELITE' all the products in elite category must be displayed. if the customer typed elite in search bar and selected the pincode 625009 in dropdown, the products for that match should be displayed. what should i do to achieve this.
[image: sample output]

Answer (score 0):

Previously i.e. before gutenberg or blocks editor WooCommerce provided layered navigation in customizer but now WooCommerce suggests using blocks provided by the WooCommerce here in the below image I highlighted the filter blocks under the category `WooCommerce` you can make use of that.

Likewise, you can build your custom filter for reference please check these source codes

[All blocks](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block)

[Product Search](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/tree/trunk/assets/js/blocks/product-search)

[Active Filters](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/tree/trunk/assets/js/blocks/active-filters)

[Price Filter](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/tree/trunk/assets/js/blocks/price-filter)

The foundation for these blocks are WordPress REST API

You can find some good example for filter in this [unit test file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/blob/trunk/assets/js/utils/test/get-query.js)

[image: Shop filters]

Comment: did you find any solution for the issue I've asked a day before, that question was closed...

Comment: Sorry, don't know what question you're saying? Please share the link.

Comment: @cbra I'm not familiar with this plugin, please ask your query here https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/search-filter/